# create new column in dataframe conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

**updated question**

by using the code below i am able to access dataframe only after completion of for loop, but i want to use most recently created column of the dataframe at intermediate time. i.e after every 5 minutes whichever is the last column of the dataframe ,how to achieve this?

```
@app.route("/sortbymax")
def sortbymax():
    df = updated_data()
    #### here i want to use most recently created column
    df = create_links(df)
    df = df.sort_values(by=['perc_change'], ascending=False)
    return render_template('sortbymax.html',tables=[df.to_html(escape = False)], titles=df.columns.values)


def read_data():
    filename = r'c:\Users\91956\Desktop\bk.xlsm'
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)    
    return df


def updated_data():
    df = read_data()
    for i in range(288): 
        temp = read_data()
        x=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        df['perc_change_'+x] = temp['perc_change']
        time.sleep(300)
    return df
```

Comment: When you say 'these values change continuously' how do they change and where are the new values found?

Comment: i am refering to values in column last5min

Comment: my question is , if i have one column in dataframe in which values keep on changing , i want to save them after every 5 min. in new columns

Comment: Can you describe your data further? You have an original column and many other columns that represent perc_change that happen every 5 minutes. Is it correct? My question is where do you get these values from? Is it an API or something? How do you know the new values? And finally, regarding your question: you want the new columns to include only values that changed and those that didn;t change to be empty?

Comment: So the column per_change is updated continuously from some algorithm and you want to keep 'pictures' of this column every 5 minutes?

Comment: No. when i read excel sheet it has only one column that is perc_change. i want to create new columns every 5 min. suppose i start reading data at 10:00. at 10:05 new column in dataframe should get added which will contain values of perc_change at 10:05. again at 10:10 new columns should get generated which will contain values of perc_change at 10:10 and so on.

Comment: i am importing live data in excel and saving that excel sheet after every 1 second using macro. this is how values keep on changing in perc_change column

Comment: i dont want picutres , they are shown just to explain question, i want columns to be generated in dataframe

Comment: By 'pictures' i mean a copy of the column. No worries, i got the issue, take a look at my suggestion and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have a file .xlsm which means is a macro enabled excel. I guess you can read it but if you want to change it with python than you most probably lose the macro part in your excel.

For the python part:
this will copy the perc_change column every 5 minutes, with the respective name. However bear in mind that this will work only for one day (it will replace existing columns after that). If you want to work for longer periods, let me know so that I will add day-month-year (whatever you want) in column names.

```
import datetime
import time

def read_data():
    filename = r'c:\Users\91956\Desktop\bk.xlsm'
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)    
    return df

def write_data(df):
    filename = r'c:\Users\91956\Desktop\bk.xlsm'
    df.to_excel(filename)    
    
df = read_data() #read excel for first time

for i in range(288): #this will run for one day exactly
    temp = read_data()
    x=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    df['perc_change_'+x] = temp['perc_change']
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: no. one day is fine, thanks for help, will check tomorrow, when live feed starts and will let you know. thanks again

Comment: as there is infinite loop should i keep this code and dataframe in some other python file and from there access it in main.py, i am creating a flask app.

Comment: I would suggest to run it seperately, no need to be part of the flask app. If you want we can add a counter in while loop so that it will run for x times (eg 288 for one day)

Comment: creating columns in dataframe only serves the purpose, no need to write data to excel

Comment: Even if you don't want to write the data to excel, you must still read the excel file in each iteration, to get the new values. In this case you must use a separate dataframe, one to read the excel and another to add the additional columns per 5 minutes

Comment: yes thats true, need to read excel in each iteration.  i tried running below code ideally it should create three new columns, right? but only one new column gets created                         for i in range(3):
    df = read_data()
    x=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    df['perc_change_'+x] = df['perc_change']
    # write_data(df)
    time.sleep(5)

print(df)                                                                                                                                          why so?

Comment: Really strange. Can you add a `print(x)` after x=datetime...etc and see what is printed? Are all 3 x's different?

Comment: three different x values 19:53:55
19:54:00
19:54:05  but still column gets created only for last value

Comment: even tried printing df before time.sleep(5) only latest x value column gets created

Comment: This happens because we read data in every iteration. I updated the code. It now reads the data for first time, saves it in df and in every iteration we use a temp dataframe to read excel again and update the df. Please try again and let me know

Comment: yes, i too thought so , implemented and read the comment, it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225990/discussion-between-aniket-patil-and-ioatzimas).